# How to left justify text using css flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Each of the two rows are set to `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between`. They aren't aligned to the red line the way I want them to since the texts are of different lengths. How can I line them up in a way that the text length doesn't matter and they will always be left justified?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please post enough code in the question so that we can reproduce the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the second line, the center element (text) is expanded because the width of the text is larger.
If you want all lines to be aligned on the left and right (for the opt-in button) you should have a look at the `flex-shrink` and `flex-grow`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink